# WAMP to XAMPP WordPress transfer

Tags: plugins, widgets, localhost, migration, xampp

I want to switch a WordPress site from a wamp localhost to xampp localhost. Using the Tools > Export, I saved the WordPress content to an XML file. I did not create a similar backup of the MySQL databases (and won't be able to) but have all the files from wamp.

How can I make this transfer without having to install a new version of WordPress? There are important settings in widgets and plugins that I need preserved. I am looking to place the relevant wamp and WordPress files in the correct xampp and WordPress folders.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know where WAMP and XAMPP keeps the actual database files, but you can move those files from one LAMP install to another. I assume the same is true for moving between WAMP and XAMPP, but I don't know for sure. However, this is off-topic here per the [faq]. Try [sf] or [so] maybe.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing by FAR is going to be to fire up MAMP again, create a MySQL dump of the database from phpmyadmin, and then import that into your new XAMP database through phpmyadmin.

If you can't do that, it might still be doable, but will be more work and confusing... I never got it to work right trying copying the files from one folder to the other.

Answer (score 1):

1. login to `localhost/phpMyAdmin` and create dump of your DB
2. Configure XAMPP and install clean Wordpress
3. Import dump of your old DB to new Wordpress
4. Change `site_url` and 'home`in`wp_options` table
5. Copy all your plugins from `plugins` folder and themes from `themes` folder
6. Copy all uploaded files from `uploads' folder
7. Check if everything goes well.

Those points are general but maybe you'r site will need some custom tweaks after migration...

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using the following plugin for the process of duplicating a WordPress site from one server to another (WAMP to XAMPP).

Duplicator
https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/

It'll package up the entire site, core and all. Provides you a Zip and a Installer. You then simply copy the Zip and Installer PHP file to the other server, access it via the URL and it'll unzip everything, and also connect to the database you've set-up (it'll ask you for the DB details) (whether empty or full) and re-build everything with the appropriate changes such as new base URL etc.

Answer (score 0):

install updraftplus in the main site and make a backup. download all those files. install updraftplus in localhost site. put the downloaded files in updraftplus folder of the local install. The software will recognize the backup and you can restore it. everything will work without a single option missing.
if software doesnot prompt you to change the url, do it manually by changing site_url and home dir in wp_options table.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is:

Save all your WP files to pc
Go to phpmyadmin find the database, user for wordpress export the database

Then on new server upload all WP files, go to phpmyadmin create user, database import database then in the WP files find the file called database.php open that and edit database name, password and user according to what you created.